# While string contains invalid character don't continue using while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to make the user continue to enter a sentence as long as it has a character in it that isn't in the alphabet or a space using a while loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
plaintext = input("Enter the sentence to encode or decode: ")

    alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
                'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ']
    contin = True
    for i in range(0,len(plaintext)):
        while plaintext[i] not in alphabet:
            contin = False
    while not contin:
        plaintext = input("Enter the sentence to encode or decode: ")
```

Comment: Well what is exactly wrong? You have debugged your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O','P', 'Q', 'R','S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ']

okey = True
string = ''
while okay is True:
    tmp = input()
    if tmp in alphabet:
        string += tmp
    elif tmp not in alphabet:
        okay = False

print(string)
```

But, the user needs to press enter/return every time s/he inputs any character.

Comment: Take a look at this now

Comment: Is there a way to make it so they can enter an entire string?

Comment: You can take the whole string as input at once and then process the string until finding any not allowed character.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ']

while True:
  plaintext = input("Enter the sentence to encode or decode: ")
  plaintext_list = [*plaintext]
  if set(plaintext) & set(alphabet):
    break
```